# Is there a package for computing and discretizing Euler-Lagrange equations?

Tags: optimization

I have an energy functional that I want to optimize using the calculus of variations. Is there any software package that will do this automatically?

As far as I can tell, Maple and Mathematic have some relevant functionality, and they can generate C code as well. However, I could not find a working example. Are there any available working examples that use Mathematica?

Are there any other specialized packages that will solve these sorts of problems?

Comment: I'm going to bump this over to Computational Science, since this is much more relevant there. Also, from what you describe you should read up on finite element methods. They may be quite applicable.

Answer (score 4):

The question of course all depends on what kind of problem you have. If you have an energy functional that describes the position of a weight suspended from a spring, then the Euler-Lagrange equations are just an algebraic equation. On the other hand, if you have an energy equation that is described using an ODE, e.g. the position of a chain suspended from its end points as gravity acts on it, then you will get a two-point boundary value problem. Finally, if you have a multi-dimensional problem, then the Euler-Lagrange equations will be partial differential equations.

The point I want to make is that the type of problem you get in the Euler-Lagrange equations depends very much on the situation you are considering, and so the question of what discretization method to use can not be answered without seeing more context.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica has the package `VariationalMethods` which you may want to take a look at:
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/VariationalMethods/tutorial/VariationalMethods.html

For an example of how to set up the Euler-Lagrange equations for a problem and then use Mathematica to solve them, see the first example here:
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/VariationalMethods/ref/EulerEquations.html

Comment: I wanted something which also descretize the equations

Comment: Use `NDSolve` instead of `DSolve`. http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html